# Url/webpages blank in chrome for azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, migration, azure-devops-server-2020

Recently we have migrated from TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps 2020. After this we are unable to access the project/settings/agents pools page in chrome outside server and inside server. However, we are able to see the homepage. But we are able to access all the pages and urls within server only via firefox.  any help is appreciated

Comment: Since at this time, Azure DevOps 2020 is still an RC, I'd think you'd get more ready feedback logging this on the Microsoft Developer community.  The RC2 is supposed to be production supported, so I'm sure they'd probably tackle any issues pretty quickly.

Comment: `After this we are unable to access the project/settings/agents pools page in chrome outside server and inside server.` For this, have you tried same actions with IE browser or Edge browser? What's the result if you restart the org and test it again?